# Get current map camera's center location by Google Map API in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

I am developping an Android app which involves a `PickLocationActivity.java`. This activity should allow user to drag(move) the map, and when they hit a `submitButton`, the location(longitute and latitute) of current camera's center should be collected. I am trying this by setting a Pin above the map and in the center of the layout in the xml file, just like this:

[Get the location of pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9B3f.jpg)

I am trying `Log.d` to see if the location info has been collected. However, **nothing shows up in my logcat.**

#### PickLocationActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        submitButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);


        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LatLng myFocus = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                Log.d("PickLocationActivity", Double.toString(myFocus.latitude)+Double.toString(myFocus.longitude));
            }
        });
    }
```

#### activity_pick_location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.safer.PickLocationActivity" >



<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PickLocationActivity" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:hoveredFocusedTranslationZ="0dp"
        app:maxImageSize="50dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pin" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/danganRed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So the goal is **after user moves the map and clicks the submit button, collect the location of pin and show it in log.**

In logcat, I filter the messages by `pick` but it always returns nothing. I wonder if it is correct to use `mMap.getCameraPosition().target` to get the location of pin?

Comment: Your tag log is PickLocationActivity not pickup

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA Oh, typing error! Editted, thanks!

Comment: `mMap.getCameraPosition().target` is used to get the center LatLng of the map fragment. Since the pin is at the center of the fragment, the code seems okay.

Comment: Log filter is case-sensitive - `pick` is not the same as `Pick` (from PickLocationActivity tag).